# dequeue in Queue of Data Structure?

Tags: data-structures, queue

I can't understand one paragraph When I read the Data Structure and Algorithm Analysis in Java. Anybody can tell me?

*In applications where you are sure that the number of enqueues is not larger than the capacity of the queue, the wraparound is not necessary. As with stacks, dequeues are rarely performed unless the calling routines are certain that the queue is not empty. Thus error checks are frequently skipped for this operation, except in critical code. This is generally not justifiable, because the time savings that you are likely to achieve are minimal.*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full context in which this paragraph sits, an exact answer might be difficult.  It appears to saying that dequeue operations are only performed when the queue is known to not be empty.  Therefore, error checks for an empty queue are frequently skipped for this operation, on the basis that it is saving time by not performing the check.  However, the time savings realized by not doing the empty check are minimal, and the risk of not checkout outweighs the minimal performance gain.

In more human readable terms, when working with queues (as with stacks), there is a potential need to make sure that the queue is not empty before trying to do a dequeue (removal) operation.  Often this check is ignored on the grounds that it saves time and boosts performance.  But the book you are reading feels that the increase in performance is small and is outweighed by the risk of not performing the empty check.